# If my .htaccess is set up to 301 from abc.com to xyz.com, what would cause abc.com to be 302-ing instead?

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

Here's what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#rewritecond %{http_host} !^abc.com/* [nc]
#rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1 [r=301,L]
```

But when I check the headers for abc.com, I get:

```
Status: HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
```

abc.com and xyz.com are hosted on the same server; xyz.com is the new domain name.

Is there something superseding the original .htaccess? I'd asked the hosting company to do the redirects, and they say that they used their 'park domain' functionality to do it. But I'm still not sure how that could prevent the .htaccess rules from being followed.

Answer (score 2):

The `#` at the start of those lines means that they're commented out.  Something else is doing the redirect.